# Routes using cookie authentication from previous version of Paw no longer work on new version

Tags: paw-app

I have a route that uses an authentication cookie set by another route. I've created it like this:
[image: cookie authenticated route]

This method no longer works in the new version. Paw complains that there is no set-cookie header in the response from the Authenticate request.

It seems this is because Paw now takes the cookies and handles them differently from other headers. I like this approach because it should make this sort of authentication easier, but, unfortunately, it's not working like I would expect.

Here's how I have configured a newer request:
[image: cookie authenticated request configured using the cookie jar]

So, I've set the cookie header to the `Response Cookies` dynamic value which, I believe, should pass along the cookies set previously. I would think I should select the Authenticate request from the dropdown (since it's the response from this request that actually sets the cookie, but the cookie value disappears if I do that. Instead, I have left the request value as `Current Request` since that seems to contain the correct value.

I've also noticed the `Automatically send cookies` setting which I thought might be an easy solution. I removed the manual cookie header from my request leaving this checked in hopes it might automatically send over any cookies from the cookie jar along with the request, but that doesn't seem to work either. No matter what I try, my request fails to produce the desired results because of authentication.

[image: Automatically send cookies setting]

Can you help me understand how to configure these requests so that I can continue using Paw to test session-authenticated routes?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of things that will make you understand how cookies work in Paw (starting from version 2.1):

**1. Cookies are stored in Jars**

To allow users to keep multiple synchronous sessions, cookies are stored in jars, so you can switch between sessions (jars) easily.

Cookies stored in jars will be sent only if they **match** the request (hostname, path, is secure, etc.).

**2. Cookies from jars are sent by default, unless `Cookie` header is overridden**

If you set a `Cookie` header manually, cookies stored in jars wont' be sent.
And obviously unless *Automatically Send Cookies* is disabled.

**3. The previous use of *"Response Headers"* was hacky. Use *Response Cookies*.**

In fact, `Set-Cookie` (for responses) and `Cookie` (for requests) have different syntaxes. So you can't send back the original value of `Set-Cookie` (even though it seemed to be working in most cases).

The new *Response Cookies* dynamic value you mentioned has this purpose: send back the cookies set by a specific request.

Now, in your case, I would use a *Response Cookies* dynamic value all the time. As you have only 1 request doing auth / cookie setting, it might be the easiest to handle. Also, maybe check **Ignore Domain, Path, Is Secure and Date** to make sure your cookie is always sent even if you switch the host (or something else).

[image: Send cookies from a specific request in Paw]

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the cookies in the cookie jar and hitting the authentication endpoint again seems to have fixed the problem. Not sure why, but it seems to be working now either manually sending a cookie or using the `Automatically send cookies` setting.

Comment: That's kind of silly. Maybe something weird was happening in your case. Anyways, I hope I gave you more precisions...