# macOS Paw - Parse response cookies for request header

Tags: cookies, httpresponse, paw-app

How do I parse a response cookie and sent back a specific value into a request header?

I'm making a request: it's sending back a token in a session cookie (`token=longstrong`). I need to grab that cookie, parse out `token`, and send back the value in a `x-token:` request header for following requests.

Paw is only giving me the option to send the cookie (raw).

How can I parse the response cookie to send back the *value* of `$.token` (json pseudo-code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A late reply, sorry!

This might help (from [How do i pick specific cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879712/how-do-i-pick-specific-cookies)):

Use a *Custom* dynamic value (right click on the field, and pick *Extensions* > *Custom*), instead, and use the following JavaScript code snippet:

```
function evaluate(context){
  // Set here the cookies you'd like to return
  var wantedCookies = ["datr", "reg_fb_ref"];

  var regex = /^(\w+)\=([^;\s]+)/g;

  // Request
  // Uses here the current request, you can use getRequestByName("name of the request") instead
  var request = context.getCurrentRequest();

  // Get response cookies
  var cookies = request.getLastExchange().getResponseHeaderByName("Set-Cookie").split(", ");
  var filteredCookies = [];

  for (var i in cookies) {
    var cookie = cookies[i];
    var match = regex.exec(cookie);
    if (match && wantedCookies.indexOf(match[1]) >= 0) {
      filteredCookies.push(match[0]);
    }
  }

  return filteredCookies.join(",");
};
```

That basically parses manually the response cookies, and returns the ones you need.

---

This other question might help: [Routes using cookie authentication from previous version of Paw no longer work on new version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508417/routes-using-cookie-authentication-from-previous-version-of-paw-no-longer-work-o)

Comment: Perfect! With a little tweaking for my requirements, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks, Micha.